# How to Implement a DAG-like Scheduler in Java?

Tags: java

I want to implement a simple DAG-like scheduler in Java (no result needed), described as the following graph:

[image: DAG-like scheduling]

I can simply use manual code to achieve this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<?> futureA = executor.submit(new Task("A"));
Future<?> futureC = executor.submit(new Task("C"));
futureA.get();
Future<?> futureB = executor.submit(new Task("B"));
futureB.get();
futureC.get();
Future<?> futureD = executor.submit(new Task("D"));
futureD.get();
```

But I'm looking for a more general way to do this, so I can use the scheduler like this:

```
Container container = new Container();
container.addTask("A", new Task("A"));
container.addTask("B", new Task("B"), "A");
container.addTask("C", new Task("C"));
container.addTask("D", new Task("D"), "B", "C");
container.waitForCompletion();
```

And actually I've already implement a simple one:

https://github.com/jizhang/micro-scheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shzhangji/micro_scheduler/App.java

But I need to iterate all the tasks every 100ms to see which one is ready to be submitted. Also in this implementation there's no exception checking.

I also checkout the Guava lib's ListenableFuture, but I don't know how to use it properly.

Any suggestions on how to implement a DAG, or recommending an existing opensource scheduler will be appreciated.

Comment: I you just want to run tasks `A`, `B` and `C` concurrently and then wait for them to finish why not use `invokeAll`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `B` depends on `A`, and there could be more complex graphs.

Comment: That's a non-linear pipeline.  Lookup the pipeline pattern, there are several java libraries that implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done using the google's guava library and it's listenable future interface. ListenableFutures allow you to have complex chains of asynchronous operations. You should implement a listenable future to execute task D once task B and C are completed using the allAsList method.

The documentation for Listenable Futures:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

A tutorial on Listenable Futures: 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/listenablefuture-in-guava.html

An example of using the allAsList, chain, and transform methods:
http://codingjunkie.net/google-guava-futures/

Comment: Thanks for the articles, I write one like this: https://github.com/jizhang/micro-scheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shzhangji/micro_scheduler/Container.java and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Dexecutor (Disclaimer : I am the owner) is the library you are looking for, Here is an example

```
public class WorkFlowManager {

    private final Dexecutor<String, Boolean> dexecutor;

    public WorkFlowManager(ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.dexecutor = buildDexecutor(executorService);

        buildGraph();
    }

    private Dexecutor<String, Boolean> buildDexecutor(final ExecutorService executorService) {
        DexecutorConfig<String, Boolean> config = new DexecutorConfig<>(executorService, new WorkFlowTaskProvider());
        return new DefaultDexecutor<>(config);
    }

    private void buildGraph() {
        this.dexecutor.addDependency(TaskOne.NAME, TaskTwo.NAME);
        this.dexecutor.addDependency(TaskTwo.NAME, TaskThree.NAME);
        this.dexecutor.addDependency(TaskTwo.NAME, TaskFour.NAME);
        this.dexecutor.addDependency(TaskTwo.NAME, TaskFive.NAME);
        this.dexecutor.addDependency(TaskFive.NAME, TaskSix.NAME);
        this.dexecutor.addAsDependentOnAllLeafNodes(TaskSeven.NAME);
    }

    public void execute() {
        this.dexecutor.execute(ExecutionConfig.TERMINATING);
    }
}
```

Which would build the following graph, and execution would proceed accordingly.
[image: Dexecutor Graph]

Refer [How Do I?](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core/wiki/How-Do-I-%3F) for more detail

**Why Dexecutor**

- Ultra light weight
- Ultra Fast
- Immediate/Scheduled Retry Logic supported
- Non terminating behaviour supported
- Conditionally skip the task execution
- Good test coverage to keep you safe from harm
- Available in maven central
- Good amount of documentation
- Distribute Execution Supported (Ignite, Hazelcast, Infinispan)

**Usefull links**

- [Dexecutor Blogs](https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/category/dexecutor/)
- [Dexecutor Website](https://dexecutor.github.io/#intro)
- [Dexecutor Wiki](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core/wiki)
- [Dexecutor Source Code](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible direction is [JavaRed Library](https://github.com/avivcarmis/java-red) which provides an interface for writing and defining async graph flows with a synchronous-like idiom.

As a short example, a graph flow as complex as this one:
[image: Graph execution flow]

can be simply implemented with:

```
Result<String> aResult = produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(() -> executeA());
Result<String> bResult = ifResult(aResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(a -> executeB(a));
Result<String> cResult = ifResult(aResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(a -> executeC(a));
Result<String> eResult = ifResult(aResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(a -> executeE(a));
Result<String> dResult = ifResults(bResult, cResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting((b, c) -> executeD(b, c));
Result<String> fResult = ifResult(eResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(e -> executeF(e));
Result<String> gResult = ifResult(fResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting(f -> executeG(f));
return ifResults(dResult, gResult).succeed().produceFutureOf(String.class).byExecuting((d, g) -> executeH(d, g));
```

More about it in the [project wiki](https://github.com/avivcarmis/java-red/wiki/The-Red-Executor-Module)

Answer (score 0):

we can use Java8 CompletableFuture to solve your problem, the core like this:

```
for (Task dependedentTask : dependedentTasks) {
    // get dependedentFuture by dependedentTask,for example
    CompletableFuture dependedentFuture = futureMap.get(dependedentTask);
    dependedentFutures.add(dependedentFuture);
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(dependedentFutures).thenRunAsync(current task execute it's method)...
```

hope someone code it.